# How to specify sql server identity

Tags: sql-server, identity, identity-column

Does anyone know how to specify the format for an identity column in sql server.
My identity column is also a primary key.

THe expected format is like:

### ID_cli --------   Name

1000 1 -------------    aaa

1000 2 -------------         bbb

1000 3  -------------        ccc

1000  12346 ------- ddd

The identity column is ID_cli
and the 1000 needs to be constant

Comment: So - you want `0001[space]1`?

Comment: Identity values should ideally never be shown to end users, and should be treated as opaque blobs that identify the row and can conveniently be stored in `int` columns. You shouldn't care about what the actual values are or any formatting. If you do insist on formatting and displaying them, does it really have to be done in the DB?

Comment: Space is irrelevant, but 0001 needs to be constant. Just the right side of number increment

Comment: Yes, it needs to be done in the DB. 
I just need to have a constant digit and other that increments

Answer (score 1):

Here is the syntax:

```
create table tablename (ID_cli int identity(100,1),
AdditionalId as '0001'+Cast(ID as Varchar(10)))
```

Here Additional Id column will have ID values always prefixed with 0001.

IDENTITY [ (seed , increment) ]

seed:Is the value that is used for the very first row loaded into the table.

increment: Is the incremental value that is added to the identity value of the previous row that was loaded.

Comment: That solution will increment the seed too, after the count reach 199.
I need that the 100 be constant

Comment: In that you can have one additional id columns as follows:  AdditionalId as '0001'+Cast(ID as Varchar(10))

Comment: Though I always suggest you to have only ID column, and prefix it with '0001' whenever you need for querying purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use just an identity for your purposes. You will need to do a custom solution. I can suggest that you have a column with the identity and a computed column that appends the "1000 " to is.